# What Does a Line Though "super(props)" Mean? See image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I'm creating a React app, and as of right now, everything working fine.  However I've noticed is VSCode that there is a line though the "super(props)" line.  Just wondering what this means? I've never seen it before, and do not understand

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strikethrough is the sign for "deprecated" - it means that VSCode thinks that the `React.Component#constructor(props)` method is deprecated (it isn't).

This is probably because you're using [the 1.49+ version of VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_49) which ships with TypeScript 4.0+.  [TypeScript 4.0 understands the `@deprecated` JSDoc tag](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0/#deprecated-support), but [there is a bug in TypeScript's support for `@deprecated` when combined with overloads](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/407#issuecomment-650266584).  Because of this, even though the [`@types/react`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/f612b4fcdf2d5c49b3779bc83b9867e5b029f760/types/react/index.d.ts#L478-L483) definition only deprecates the *second* constructor which takes in a legacy `context` argument VSCode is seeing *all* the constructors as being deprecated.  In this case the warning is safe to ignore.

Comment: Thank you.  It does say deprecated when I put the mouse over it, I just didn't understand what it meant was deprecated.  Your explanation is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, it means that the current component accepts props(prop values) from parent components. If you don't write it in the constructor, the current component couldn't get props from the parent components.
There might be more valuable and detailed answers out there, but I hope this could be helpful to improve your understanding a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

**The super() function calls the parent class's constructor.**

By calling super(props), you are calling the constructor of React.Component.
Which means that super() is a reference to the parent class constructor() which in the above case is of React.Component which is the base class of Component Audit.

Thanks.